# how to create an enum-like object with bigint initializers in typescript?

Tags: javascript, typescript

What I would ideally do is:

```
enum Distance {
    Far: 0n,
    Medium, // 1n
    Close, // 2n
}

function Calculate(length: Distance) {
    // do something here
}
```

Unfortunately enums do not support bigints yet, so that doesn't work.

I've tried something like:

```
const Distance = {
    Far: 0n,
    Medium: 1n,
    Close: 2n
}

type Distance = typeof Distance;

function Calculate(length: Distance) {
    const answer = 1n + length;
    // Operator '+' cannot be applied to types 'bigint' and '{ Far: bigint; Medium: bigint; Close: bigint }'
}
```

But that doesn't seem to work (I can't use it as I would a normal enum).

I know I can just cast the number to a bigint with `BigInt()` but I'd rather not do that.

How can I create something that functions like an enum because that uses bigints instead of numerals or strings?

Comment: I simplified my use-case for the question, but the idea is the same. Basically the enum value is used in a loop that can done called tens or hundreds of thousands of times. Even for a small number, casting the value to a bigint (with `BigInt()`) takes a noticable amount of time over 1 million plus iterations. Having the enum values be bigints already would mean I don't have to cast.

Comment: Sometimes I do need stuff typed Distance.Far or Distance.Medium (like `if (distance === Distance.Far)` kinda thing. Other times I'm passing something into a function that should be a Distance type and then using that value in a math operation.

Comment: Oh, well then. I don't think I need anything actually typed Distance.Far, etc. I'm pretty sure I'm just using them as constant values.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your initial idea of using a constant object instead is good. Your mistake is your `type Distance` that isn't what you expect:

[image: Intellisense tooltip of Distance type]

Your values are bigints, therefore use `bigint` as type:

```js
const Distance = {
    Far: 0n,
    Medium: 1n,
    Close: 2n
}

type Distance = bigint;

function Calculate(length: Distance) {
    const answer = 1n + length;
}
```

You'll see that this will work, since both `1n` and `length` will be bigints.