# Bigint in TS enum

Tags: javascript, typescript

I am wondering if there are possible alternatives to TS enum. I need bigint in my enum because I use this in bitwise operations.

I need something like this:

```
enum Perms {
 None = 0n,
 Basic = 1n,
 ...
}
```

then I use this in bitwise operation like:

```
hasPermission(role: Role, permission: Perms): boolean {
  return (role.permissions! & permission) !== 0;
}
```

Can I use this as:

```
const Perms = {
 None: BigInt(0),
 Basic: BigInt(1),
 ...
}
```

?
But there is an error in `hasPermission` method:
`'Perms' refers to a value, but is being used as a type here. Did you mean 'typeof Perms'?`

Comment: `enum` types in TypeScript are more than just named-constants - you _might_ be better-off by using just "raw" named `const` `BigInt` values, especially because an `enum` type is meant to be closed/exhaustive, but a bitwise combinations of flags won't all be valid defined enum members, y'see...

Comment: `!== 0` is a big mistake, that'll always return `true` if you test a bigint. You'll need `!== 0n` instead! Although I'd recommend `return (role.permissions! & permission) === permission;`

Comment: Do you actually have more than 32 different permissions?

Comment: btw: https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/37783

Comment: Another approach is to _avoid trying to be smart_ and instead have a `type Perms = 'none' | 'basic' | 'etc';` and a normal `class` that encapsulates a `Set<Perms>` and a simple method-based API for adding/removing/testing membership. (Bitfields are very space-efficient, but JavaScript/TypeScript _is not_, so trying to be-space-efficient in JavaScript is like being a Hummer owner trying to be eco-friendly by hypermiling but only gaining +1 MPG - it's wasted effort)

Comment: Actually I dont need more than 32 but I just wonder is it possible.

Comment: Maybe @Dai should write up an answer, since the current answer doesn't seem to be very useful.

Comment: @jcalz If I did, some people would argue I wasn't answering the OP's _stated_ question, even if I was providing a solution to their underlying problem.

Comment: @Dai The question seems to say "I am wondering if there are possible alternatives to TS enum." so an answer that suggests using something other than an enum *seems* to be on topic.  Anyway, I'd be happy to write up something similar if you don't want to.

Answer (score 0):

The type of:

```
enum Perms { ... }
```

is an enum. If you want to have a type of values present in the enum, I suggest to declare specific `type`. It's generally good practice to have the naming appropriately reflect the business logic in the code.

What I mean by that, is when you have e.g.: function

```
hasPermission(role: Role, permission: Perms): boolean {
```

it has a conflict of the second argument `permission` (singular) being a type of `Perms` (plural).

A more appropriately defined type would be:

```
enum Perms {
    None = BigInt(0),
    Basic = BigInt(1),
}

type Perm = Perms.None | Perms.Basic
```

Then you use the actual **enum value type**, and not **enum type**.

```
hasPermission(role: Role, permission: Perm): boolean {
```

---

Regarding the logic of the function, as @Bergi commented, you would need `!== 0n` comparison instead of `!== 0`, if you test a bigint type.

Comment: Thanks for replay :) The problem is BigInt in TS enum, there is no possibility to use it in enum, there is an error `Type 'bigint' is not assignable to type 'number' as required for computed enum member values.` That why I've created this post.

Comment: I see - why aren't you considering a simpler solution, using `Number` type?

For `BigInt` I would recommend to have a look at [post that seems to have a similar topic](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68458827/22772416)

Comment: I am testing solution from the link and it seems to fit my case :)

Comment: This answer doesn't seem to be relevant to the question; you are mostly discussing *naming* instead of the error message the question asks about, and your suggestion has the same error.  The problem here is that bigints are not allowed in enums, not that the word `Perms` is plural.